# Is it good to use AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin in listview having large amount of children like 1,00,000.?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am using AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin to keep widgets in my list view alive but while scrolling it feels like it is hanging a lot , i mean scrolling is not smooth and   also there are duplicate widgets in list.

Comment: Are you running you application in debug mode?

Comment: Yes , i am running it in my AVD emulator.

Comment: emulator is different and debug mode is different.

Comment: NO i am not running it in debug mode then

Comment: To know your app is running in `debug` mode, you'll see a red ribbon like thing(with debug written on it) at the top right corner of your app if you didn't set `debugShowCheckedModeBanner:` to false

Comment: Yes , it is there

Answer (score 0):

In `debug mode`, the compiler emits debug symbols for all variables and compiles the code as is. You can't judge your app performance in `debug` mode

In `release mode`, some optimizations are included:

1. Unused variables do not get compiled at all
2. Some loop variables are taken out of the loo.p by the compiler if they are proven to be invariants.
3. Code written in `debug` directive is not included, etc.

In release mode only you can judge your app performance. So, don't worry about the smoothness or the performance of the app

Comment: But can i use AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin for 1 lakh or greater widgets in listview, does it impact the performance of app  by putting to much load

Comment: It may impact the app performance i guess, because 1 lakh is a big number.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `Pagination` if you have 1,00,000 items to be displayed in your ListView. That would help in some performance gain I believe.